# Cancel a promise from the 'then'

Tags: promise, bluebird, cancellation

I just switched to promises and I'm sure I got something wrong but I can't figure out what.
In the following code, I'd like to cancel the promise if _getDevice() returns null (it's a `mongodb.findOneAsync()` under the hood).

From my perspective if _getDevice returns null, the promise should be cancelled and I should see the 'CANCEL REPLY' log. But instead I'm getting the 'SAVE REPLY' log.

I'm using the bluebird library.

```
var promise = Promise.props({
    device: _getDevice(event.deviceId),
    events: _getEvents(event.deviceId, event.date)
}).cancellable();

promise.then(function (result) {
    if (! result.device) {
        return promise.cancel()
    }

    var device = new Device(result.device);
    var events = result.events;

    // ...

    return db.collection(collections.devices).saveAsync(device.toMongoDocument());
}).then(function () {
    console.log('SAVE REPLY');
    return req.reply(null);
}).catch(Promise.CancellationError, function (err) {
    console.log('CANCEL REPLY')
    return req.reply(null);
}).catch(function (error) {
    return req.reply(error);
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot cancel a promise from the `then` callback, as the execution of that callback means that the promise has been resolved. It's impossible to change the state afterwards.

What you probably want to do is *throw an error* from the handler, resulting in the rejection of the new promise that was returned from `then()`.

You even might do that before the two promises are joined, so that the `getEvents` promise is cancelled when the `getDevice` promise fails:

```
Promise.props({
    device: _getDevice(event.deviceId).then(function(device) {
        if (!device)
            throw new Promise.CancellationError(); // probably there's a better error type
        else
            return new Device(device);
    },
    events: _getEvents(event.deviceId, event.date) // assuming it is cancellable
}).then(function (result) {
    var device = result.device;
    var events = result.events;

    // ...

    return db.collection(collections.devices).saveAsync(device.toMongoDocument());
}).then(function () {
    console.log('SAVE REPLY');
    return req.reply(null);
}).catch(Promise.CancellationError, function (err) {
    console.log('CANCEL REPLY')
    return req.reply(null);
}).catch(function (error) {
    return req.reply(error);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the accepted answer is entirely correct; see [Cancelling Long Promise Chains](http://openmymind.net/Cancelling-Long-Promise-Chains/) -- it *is* possible to cancel a promise from within `then()`. However I am not sure what exactly the issue is with the original question (the behavior wasn't really described).

Try putting `.cancellable()` at the end of the second promise as well.

Comment: Of course you can cancel arbitrary promises from `then` callbacks, but a promise cannot cancel itself from its own callback, which is what the OP attempted to do.

Comment: Okay, I guess I did not see the distinction. Thanks.

Comment: One thing worth mentioning is that the whole cancellation API is being considered for a rewrite: https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/issues/415